# import csv in folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I read CSV files and add a column with the fruitname to each one? (I then append both files)

```
path_folder_with_2_csvs = Path(r"folder_with_2_csvs")
fruits = ['apple', 'banana']

for fruit in fruits:
    temp2 = pd.read_excel(f"fruits") for f in path_folder_with_2_csvs .rglob("*")
    temp2['fruit'] = fruit
```

The files in the folder, folder_with_2_csvs, are:

```
'apple.csv'
'banana.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read_csv` and `.to_csv`

**Ex:**

```
for f in path_folder_with_2_csvs.rglob("*.csv"):
    temp2 = pd.read_csv(f)
    temp2['fruit'] = fruits
    temp2.to_csv(f, index=False)
```